# Getting first week of date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of table and i need to get the gross income of a movie, now my problem is i don't know how to get the sum of first week only of a movie.

This is what i need.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|    title  |   Week one      |  Week one   |
|           |   (Wed-Sun)     | (Mon-Tue)   |
+-------------------------------------------+
| title 1   | 50000           |    10000    |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

If the starting show of a movie is wed then i should make 3 column, first column is *title*, second column is the *wed-sun* and third is *mon-tue*.

Is this possible to query like `select movie, sum(wed-sun), sum(mon-tue)`
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a column starting_show_date in your movies table? What's your tables structure? Can you post them on?

Comment: I guess the third column should be `Week two` not `Week one`, isn't it?

Comment: yeah there is. I have a lot of table, and your getting confuse if i post it

Comment: You could simplify them, only need columns related to the result you want. Your result is not much complicate.

Comment: Another question is if the column name would be different when the starting show dates of movies is different? Can the columns to be named as `title`, `Week one`, `Week two`?

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer based on how I understand your question.

```
SELECT movie, sum(wed-sun), sum(mon-tue) CONVERT(date, getdate()) as day
FROM thetable
WHERE thedate(BETWEEN first AND last) 
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user DAYOFWEEK() if you are using date type for that. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

For week days from mon-tue

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=2 THEN 1 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

For week days from wed-sun

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=4 THEN 1 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=5 THEN 1 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=6 THEN 1 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=7 THEN 1 WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use WEEKDAY instead of DAYOFWEEK you can shorten the case statements:

```
SELECT
     movie_id, 
     title,
     SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(date_field) < 2 THEN field_to_sum ELSE 0 END) `mon-tue`,
     SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(date_field) > 1 THEN field_to_sum ELSE 0 END) `wed-sun`
FROM
    movies
/* optional WHERE */
GROUP_BY movie_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want [WEEKDAY FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday), it returns the weekday index starting from 0-Monday.

Assume you have table `Movies` with `title` and `starting_show_date` columns, and `value_table` with `action_date` and `amount` columns.

You can sum amount by splitting amounts to two parts like this:

```
select
    movies.title,
    sum(case when value_table.action_date
        < dateadd(movies.starting_show_date , interval  7 -WEEKDAY(movies.starting_show_date) day)
             then value_table.amount else 0 end) as FirstWeek,
    sum(case when value_table.action_date
        >= dateadd(movies.starting_show_date , interval  7 -WEEKDAY(movies.starting_show_date) day)
             then value_table.amount else 0 end) as OtherWeeks
from
    movies
inner join
    value_table
on
    movies.id = value_table.movie_id
group by 
    movies.title
```